# Using multiprocessing/threading to read the serial port and live graph data with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading, python-multiprocessing, pyserial

I need to live graph data at a high rate. I need to continuously query the serial port to retrieve data when it is available. The data then modifies the instance variables that I am graphing. I am graphing 4 different lines on two sub plots so 8 lines in total. I am receiving 12 different variables, but only graphing 8. I need the process not to die out after running the function one time this way i can keep receiving new data. I want the plotting to be done in another process so that it doesnt block reading the serial port. I have found examples and have gotten assistance on how to accomplish this if i have all of the data already available but not if it's continuously receiving new data and I am new to multiprocessing/threading so it's hard to understand how to modify it to continously read from the serial port. I can accomplish what I need to at a rate of 10Hz but I need to sample at 20Hz and it seems that the only way would be through multiprocessing/threading unless I'm missing something that would optimize the graphing or read time. Here is a Tkinter window that will query the serial port when the go button is pressed and graph:

```
import Tkinter
import serial
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from collections import deque
import random
import time

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.t = 0
        self.arduinoData = serial.Serial('com5', 250000, timeout=None)

        frame = Tkinter.Frame(master)

        self.running = False
        self.ani = None

        self.run = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Testing", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10)
        self.run.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.run_respiration = Tkinter.Button(self.run, text="RUN",bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.getData)
        self.run_respiration.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)

        self.test_options = Tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="Test Options", borderwidth=10, relief=Tkinter.GROOVE, padx=10, pady=10 )
        self.test_options.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=20, pady=20)

        self.stop = Tkinter.Button(self.test_options, text="STOP", bd=10, height=5, width=10, command=self.stopTest)
        self.stop.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)


        self.fig = plt.Figure()
        self.ax1 = self.fig.add_subplot(211)
        self.line0, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line1, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line2, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line3, = self.ax1.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.ax2 = self.fig.add_subplot(212)
        self.line4, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line5, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line6, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.line7, = self.ax2.plot([], [], lw=2)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig,master=master)
        self.canvas.show()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=0, column=4, padx=20, pady=20)
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=20, pady=20)

    def getData(self):
        if self.ani is None:
            self.k = 0
            self.arduinoData.flushInput()
            self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
            return self.start()
        else:
            self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
            self.arduinoData.flushInput()
            self.ani.event_source.start()
        self.running = not self.running

    def stopTest(self):
        self.arduinoData.write("<H>")
        if self.running:
            self.ani.event_source.stop()
        self.running = not self.running

    def start(self):
        self.xdata = []
        self.pressure1 = []
        self.displacement1 = []
        self.cycle1 = []
        self.pressure2 = []
        self.displacement2 = []
        self.cycle2 = []
        self.pressure3 = []
        self.displacement3 = []
        self.cycle3 = []
        self.pressure4 = []
        self.displacement4 = []
        self.cycle4 = []
        self.k = 0
        self.limit = 300
        self.arduinoData.flushInput()
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
            self.fig,
            self.update_graph,
            interval=1,
            repeat=True)
        self.arduinoData.write("<L>")
        self.running = True
        self.ani._start()

    def update_graph(self, i):
        if (self.arduinoData.inWaiting()>0):
            self.xdata.append(self.k)
            x = self.arduinoData.readline()
            self.setData(x)
            strip_data = x.strip()
            split_data = x.split("|")
            actuator1 = split_data[0].split(".")
            actuator2 = split_data[1].split(".")
            actuator3 = split_data[2].split(".")
            actuator4 = split_data[3].split(".")
            self.pressure1.append(int(actuator1[0]))
            self.displacement1.append(int(actuator1[1]))
            self.cycle1 = int(actuator1[2])
            self.pressure2.append(int(actuator2[0]))
            self.displacement2.append(int(actuator2[1]))
            self.cycle2 = int(actuator2[2])
            self.pressure3.append(int(actuator3[0]))
            self.displacement3.append(int(actuator3[1]))
            self.cycle3 = int(actuator3[2])
            self.pressure4.append(int(actuator4[0]))
            self.displacement4.append(int(actuator4[1]))
            self.cycle4 = int(actuator4[2])
            self.line0.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure1)
            self.line1.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure2)
            self.line2.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure3)
            self.line3.set_data(self.xdata, self.pressure4)
            self.line4.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement1)
            self.line5.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement2)
            self.line6.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement3)
            self.line7.set_data(self.xdata, self.displacement4)
            if self.k < 49:
                self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.pressure1)-1, max(self.pressure4) + 1)
                self.ax1.set_xlim(0, self.k+1)
                self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.displacement1)-1, max(self.displacement4) + 1)
                self.ax2.set_xlim(0, self.k+1)
            elif self.k >= 49:
                self.ax1.set_ylim(min(self.pressure1[self.k-49:self.k])-1, max(self.pressure4[self.k-49:self.k]) + 1)
                self.ax1.set_xlim(self.xdata[self.k-49], self.xdata[self.k-1])
                self.ax2.set_ylim(min(self.displacement1[self.k-49:self.k])-1, max(self.displacement4[self.k-49:self.k]) + 1)
                self.ax2.set_xlim(self.xdata[self.k-49], self.xdata[self.k-1])
            if self.cycle1 >= self.limit:
                self.running = False
                self.ani = None
                self.ani.event_source.stop()
                self.running = not self.running
            self.k += 1



root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If anyone can help with my understanding of multiprocessing or provide an example that would be great. Thank you

Comment: you could just set a timer to repeat the function after so many ticks. If you just want to constantly run that function u can do this with `.after()`. `self.function_to_get_data.after(100, lambda: self.function_to_get_data())`

Comment: The get data function I am using is called by the animation function how would I be able to use after so that they're both called and won't block each others execution

Comment: is the animation function called more than once?

Comment: The interval that is set in the animation function should call it as soon as the function is done its iteration of read then graph

Comment: You could have a function that is call on a timer that will first run the function that gets the data then runs the function that graphs the data.

Comment: Did you run into a problem? you removed your comment from my answer. So I am left a little confused.

Comment: I hadn't realized that I was running it at 10Hz at 20Hz the same issue occured as before

Answer (score 2):

If you provide a timer you can have a function that will manage your events for you.

For example:

```
import time
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

def getData():
    print("getData")

def update_graph():
    print("update_graph")

def timed_events():
    getData()
    update_graph()
    root.after(1000, timed_events) # you can change the number to anything you need

timed_events()

root.mainloop()
```

this will call each function in order ever 1 sec and print:

```
getData
update_graph
```

This was just a simple example to illustrate how you could handle your data processing on a timer.

Update:

Here is another posible option with your code.
In your `start(self):` method add an if statement to the end to repeat the method `if self.x == True:`. Then all you need to do is create a button that toggles the variable `self.x` so you can stop the loop when you want.

```
self.x == True

    def start(self):
        # all your code so far
        if self.x == True:
            self.start
```

Comment: Sorry I had spoken too soon after trying to run it at 20Hz it was still too slow it ran fine at slightly above what i had before which was 10Hz

Comment: Ah. Well I would imaging there is a solution for you with a little more research. When I get home from work today I will take a look if no one has presented you with a better option :)

Comment: Sounds great thanks for going out of your way to help I've been stuck on this for awhile now

Comment: For me its about the learning process. I have only been programing for a little over 4 months now and I find the best way to learn is to work on others problems :)

Comment: Did you have any luck

Comment: emg184. Actually no. Not yet. I need a little more info. When you say you are running at 20hz what does that mean. Is the system you are monitoring running at 20hz? or your program?

Comment: The system I am monitoring (an arduino) is spitting out data to the serial port in this format integer.integer.integer|integer.integer.integer|integer.integer.integer|integer.integer.integer it does this every 50 milliseconds which is 20Hz. My python gui then collects this data and attempts to graph it in real time.

Comment: can you not change `root.after(1000, timed_events)` to `root.after(50, timed_events)`? Or maybe  a little lower so the program can keep up with the refresh rate. `root.after(25, timed_events)`

Comment: The update graph call is called in the animation function interval.         'self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.setData, interval=1, repeat=True)' where you declare interval. The code that reads the serial data i could change to .after(50, ) and I did however that actually made it slower than just leaving it as .after(10, ) or .after(1, )

Comment: ohhhhh I see. Let me take another look.

Comment: @emg184: So take a look at my updated program. go back to the code you started with and add the if statement and x variable from my example and let me know if that does what you need. The idea is to have your program repeat the method after you have put it into motion. Therefor it will continue as fast as it can process the info.

Comment: The issue wasn't stopping the loop. It's really two things. The speed at which the lines can be made and the speed at which the data can be read. I havent had any problem stopping the loom the problem is the data is getting backed up in the serial port because the combination of reading the data in and graphing the data takes longer than 50 milliseconds to perform. So say it takes 60 milliseconds. after 6 full second of operation the plot would be plotting the 100th data point while the 120th point is being added to the serial buffer.

Comment: There may be a few ways to deal with your problem. You might be able to run multiprocessing while having one process constantly update a set of global variables and have the other process constantly graph the values of the variables. Even if the Graphing process takes a little longer than the variable updates at least it will pull the latest values and not back up your buffer. The only downside is you may miss out on a set of variables from time to time.

Comment: Yeah that's what I have been trying to figure out how to do, but I can't seem to find a way to do it. so far.

Comment: @emg184: I wish I had more experience with the multiprocessing library. I have just not needed to ever use it and I don't have a setup that I could test a similar situation on to provide you with a tested answer.